# Ionic confirmPopup then() function gets called before user interaction

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Or at least, that's what I'm thinking is happening. I have the following function:

```
function checkExistingMember() {

  var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
    title: 'Existing Member?',
    template: 'Are you an existing member?',
    cancelText: 'No',
    okText: 'Yes'
  });

  confirmPopup.then(function(res) {

    if(res) {          
      // User is existing member
      return true;
    } else {          
      // User is NOT existing member
      return false;
    }

  });

} // END checkExistingMember
```

I then call it it at the very top of my controller like so:

```
var isExistingMember = checkExistingMember();
if (isExistingMember) {
  console.log('Is existing member');
} else {
  console.log('Is NOT existing member');
}
```

But then right when it's called the console prints out `Is NOT existing member` before the user has had a chance to answer. Anyone know why this is happening?

Worth mentioning that if I call `var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm() { ...}` and `confirmPopup.then(...)` directly in my controller i.e. if I don't abstract it into a function, then everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand that you can't just return from asynchronous code. Instead you need to return a promise object

```
function checkExistingMember() {

  return $ionicPopup.confirm({
    title: 'Existing Member?',
    template: 'Are you an existing member?',
    cancelText: 'No',
    okText: 'Yes'
  })
  .then(function(res) {
    if (res) {          
      // User is existing member
      return true;
    } else {          
      // User is NOT existing member
      return false;
    }
  });

}
```

and use its chainable api:

```
checkExistingMember().then(function(isExistingMember) {
  if (isExistingMember) {
    console.log('Is existing member');
  } else {
    console.log('Is NOT existing member');
  } 
});
```

Comment: Got an empty if statement in there.. Should it be if (isExistingMember) {... ? Also, getting an error on running the function: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

Comment: Yes, of course it should be `if (isExistingMember)`. Make sure you `return $ionicPopup.confirm` from the function.